# Anybody know any good silverlight tutorials?

Tags: silverlight

As the title says :)

I've been waiting for Wrox to release "Professional silverlight 2.0" for ages but it's been delayed by nearly a year and I want to have a Play with silverlight.

Ignoring the silverlight.net site, does anyone know of any good beginners tutorials that focus on coding in Visual Studio instead of Blend?

Jon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm currently running through this [set of tutorials](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-2-end-to-end-tutorial-building-a-digg-search-client.aspx). Have been quite useful as a very basic primer into the world of Silverlight.

Comment: +1, Scott's blog is a good one to track for Silverlight related stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a 57-page article for Wrox Press called "Jumping from ASP.NET to Silverlight 2". It is focused on ramping up on the basics, and doesn't involve Blend. And it's seven bucks.

[Link is here](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Jumping-from-ASP-NET-to-Silverlight-2.productCd-0470477164.html)

Answer (score 1):

[Jesse Liberty's blog](http://jesseliberty.com/) has masses of useful learning material including tutorials and videos - highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [MSDN Silverlight page.](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlightsdk/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1821)

Answer (score 0):

While not strictly a tutorial, my collegue has been reading [Pro Silverlight in C# 2008](http://www.apress.com/book/view/1590599497) and from what I heard, he's very pleased with it. Sure, it's not free, but maybe it'll hold you over until *Professional silverlight 2.0* is released? :)

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking at Silverlight 2 In Action and Silverlight 2 Unleashed and pretty happy with both

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly tutorials, the videos on the MS official Silverlight website has good videos on all kinds of topics.
start here
 http://silverlight.net/Learn/

And watch the many screencasts here
 http://silverlight.net/Learn/videocat.aspx?cat=10

Answer (score 0):

Videos have been very helpful to me:

http://channel9.msdn.com/continuum/tutorials/
http://www.microsoft.com/showcase/en/us/details/9b002e70-78c2-4741-9093-93e42228d8d1